# Replace null in a list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like:

```
  > str(gf)
       List of 28
         $ : NULL
         $ :'data.frame':       1 obs. of  2 variables:
               ..$ x: logi NA
               ..$ y: logi NA
         $ : NULL
         $ : NULL
         $ : NULL
```

I would like to replace all `NULL`   with

```
                  data.frame(x=NA,y=NA)
```

Comment: something like `gf[sapply(gf, is.null)] <- myDat`.

Comment: reproducibe example always better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
# a list
a <- list(NULL, data.frame(x=T, y=F), NULL)
str(a)
List of 3
 $ : NULL
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: logi TRUE
  ..$ y: logi FALSE
 $ : NULL

# and replace 
modify_if(a, is.null, ~compact(a) %>% unlist())
[[1]]
    x     y 
 TRUE FALSE 

[[2]]
     x     y
1 TRUE FALSE

[[3]]
    x     y 
 TRUE FALSE 

# or
modify_if(a, is.null, ~data.frame(x=NA,y=NA))
```

Comment: you have to install the recent `tidyverse` package.